SQL not allowing deletion of related data
In SQL I have:
        CREATE TABLE Customer(
            cust_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (cust_id > 0),
            full_name TEXT NOT NULL,
            phone TEXT NOT NULL,
            address TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(address) >= 3)
        );

        CREATE TABLE "Order"(
            order_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (order_id > 0),
            date TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL
        );

        CREATE TABLE Dish(
            dish_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (dish_id > 0),
            name TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(name) >= 3),
            price NUMERIC NOT NULL CHECK (price > 0),
            is_active BOOLEAN NOT NULL
        );

        CREATE TABLE Placed(
            order_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (order_id > 0),
            cust_id INT NOT NULL CHECK (cust_id > 0),
            FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES "Order" (order_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
            FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES Customer (cust_id)
        );

When trying to delete a customer I want to delete his personal data but to keep his placed orders and not to delete them.
When trying to run:
DELETE FROM Customer WHERE cust_id = 1
I get:
update or delete on table "customer" violates foreign key constraint "placed_cust_id_fkey" on table "placed"
DETAIL:  Key (cust_id)=(1) is still referenced from table "placed".

How can I fix this?

If you delete a customer the entries in Placed with the id of that customer make no sense. Could you explain why you want to keep that data? We might find a solution if we know the motivation for this.

Either do the same with order delete cascade or delete placed yourself before deleting a customer

@nbk The OP wants to keep the entry in Placed. @Moran if you want to keep it, you'd have to allow NULL for the customer ID inside the table and use ON DELETE SET NULL. Alternatively, you could add a dummy customer and set the ID to that value, but in most cases this is non-sense. As asked before, why do you even want to keep Placed?

If you delete the customer, then the order was placed by no-one and any JOIN between the customer and order tables will 'hide' the order. You're likely much better off adding a "deleted" flag to the customer, so you can choose to ignore it if/when you want to.

Have a look on on delete cascade could be help.

Maybe it is sufficient to keep the order, so the DELETE CASCADE is from Customer TO Placed and not from Placed to "Order".
Placed as you've shown us has no additional data, but probably you didn't show us all...

You can not (and should not) delete customers from database, because the Placed table linked to Customer by foreign key. I can to advice you SOFT DELETE pattern in this case. It demand to add deleted_at column on Customer table and using this column you can mark a customer as deleted intead delete it from database.
CREATE TABLE Customer(
    cust_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CHECK (cust_id > 0),
    full_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    phone TEXT NOT NULL,
    address TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(address) >= 3),
    deleted_at timestamp
);
UPDATE Customer SET deleted_at = current_timestamp WHERE cust_id = 1;

You can try this concept here

Do it with two Commands.
UPDATE placed SET cust_id = NULL WHERE cust_id = 1;
DELETE FROM Customer WHERE cust_id = 1;

Soft deliting is a clean way, but because of the laws for example in Europe, you need to hard delete it.
